# D3 Grouped Bar Chart with JSON nested data

Tags: json, d3.js

I'm trying to create a similar grouped bar chart as this example: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051  My data is JSON coming from a MongoDB and I'm having trouble accessing some of the nested data.  I would like the chart to be by buildFixTime on the Y axis and have the X axis be by time and the bars be grouped by 'group.'  Here is an example record:

```
{
        "result" : [
                {
                        "_id" : {
                                "month" : 1,
                                "day" : 22,
                                "year" : 2014,
                                "group" : "Sales"
                        },
                        "buildFixTime" : 3710497
                },
                {
                        "_id" : {
                                "month" : 1,
                                "day" : 23,
                                "year" : 2014,
                                "group" : "Sales"
                        },
                        "buildFixTime" : 79209205
                },
                {
                        "_id" : {
                                "month" : 1,
                                "day" : 24,
                                "year" : 2014,
                                "group" : "Sales"
                        },
                        "buildFixTime" : 35611663.4
                },
                {
                        "_id" : {
                                "month" : 1,
                                "day" : 24,
                                "year" : 2014,
                                "group" : "Service"
                        },
                        "buildFixTime" : 18273221.333333332
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

After loading the JSON file I have the following code (excluding the unimportant bits):

```
// This adds new elements to the data object
data.result.forEach(function(d) {
  d.group = d._id.group;
  d.date = new Date(d._id.year, d._id.month-1, d._id.day);
});

// define the axis domains
main_x0.domain(d3.extent(data.result, function(d) { return d.date; }));
main_x1.domain(d3.ascending(data.result, function(d) { return d.group; } ));
main_y.domain(d3.extent(data.result, function(d) { return (d.buildFixTime / 1000) / 60 / 60 + 2 ; }));

// flatten out the data
var nested = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d._id.group; })
    .entries(data.result);
```

After adding the axis lines etc. I have this block, which is where the problem is.  I think that I need to be able to access the date in the transform/translate line, but I'm not sure how to get at it - should I create another D3 nest object to flatten the data further?  Thanks for the help!

```
var bar = main.selectAll(".bars")
    .data(nested)
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "g")

    // This seems to be where part of my problem is
    .attr("transform", function(d) { console.log(d); return "translate(" + main_x0(d.values.date) + ",0)"; });

bar.selectAll("rect").append("rect")
    .data(function(d) { return d.values; })
  .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { console.log(d.date); return "translate(" + main_x0(d.date) + ",0)"; })
    .attr("width", main_x1.rangeBand())
    .attr("x", function(d) { return main_x1(d.date); })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return main_y(d.buildFixTime); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return main_height - main_y(d.buildFixTime); })
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.key); });
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you're setting the `transform` on the `g` elements. For the individual bars, you have all the information necessary to place them and that's all you really need to do.

Comment: Can you clarify?  Do you want all the bars for a given month to be grouped together, or all the bars for a given "group"?

Comment: Can You Provide Proper Source I'm Struck To Build Group.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem a bit confused about your two x-scales, what each one does and when to use them.

Using the variable names from the linked example, **the x0 scale spaces the different clusters of bars across the page**.

I wasn't entirely clear what you meant by "I would like [to] have the X axis be by time and the bars be grouped by 'group.'"  I'm assuming you want all the "groups" for each month clustered together, with the different months spread out across the page.  If you instead want all the dates for each "group" to be clustered together, then the domain for x0 should be your *groups*, not your dates, and you'll have to adapt the rest of this discussion.

Because dates can be treated as continuous numbers, you can use a linear scale for them; that appears to be what you're doing, by passing in the `extent` (i.e., max and min) of the data instead of a sorted list of all possible values.  However, a linear scale doesn't have an easy method to tell you how much space there is between each datapoint, which we need for positioning and sizing the bars.  So to make everything easier, make it an ordinal scale and set its domain to the sorted dates.

The **x1 scale spaces the individual bars within a cluster**, relative to the start position of that cluster.  So the domain is the "groups" you want listed at each month.

It doesn't look like you're ever setting the range for this scale.  The range of the x1 scale is the width available for each cluster, which is determined by the band-width from the x0 scale: if you have lots of clusters, each cluster will be narrower, so the individual bars will also have to be narrower.

So your axis settings would be (assuming 20% padding between clusters, and none between individual bars):

```
// initialization
main_x0 = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, main_width], 0.2); 
main_x1 = d3.scale.ordinal();
main_y  = d3.scale.linear().range([main_height, 0] );

// once you have the data
main_x0.domain(data.result.map( function(d) { return d.date; } )
                          .sort(d3.ascending) 
               );

main_x1.domain(data.result.map( function(d) { return d.group; } )
                          .sort(d3.ascending) 
               )
       .rangeRoundBands([0, main_x0.rangeBand() ], 0);

main_y.domain(d3.extent(data.result, function(d) { return d.buildFixTime ; }));
```

*(P.S.  I'm not sure why you had all sorts of conversion equations on your y-scale domain.  You only use the raw `buildFixTime` when you plot the data, so that's what you want in your domain.  The conversion from milliseconds to hours should be done in your [`tickFormat`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#wiki-linear_tickFormat) function.)*

Then, in your graphing methods, you need to to remember that `main_x0` is your *date-cluster* scale, while `main_x1` is your *group within each date* scale.  The horizontal position of each bar is determined by first shifting it over to the start of the cluster and then shifting it over again to that group's position within the cluster.  The x0 scale, applied to the date, gives you the first shift, while the x1 scale, applied to the group, gives you the second shift.

In other words, if you want a layout like this:

```
abcde  abcde  abcde  abcde
 Jan.   Feb.   Mar.   Apr.  
       *             
       >>>>|
```

Then to find the position for category "e" for February, you would need x0(Feb) + x1(e).  The first gives you the start of the February cluster (marked `*`), the second gives you the additional shift to get to category e (marked with `>`).

Your data is nested by "group".  So each of your `<g>` elements consists of all the bars in a particular category: all the `a`s in one, all the `b`s in another.  While you *could* use a transform on your `<g>` elements to shift the start point of each group according to how much shift that group requires in each cluster, I think that would be complicating things.  As Lars says, you can do it all when positioning individual bars.

So your code would look like:

```
var bar = main.selectAll(".bars")
    .data(nested)
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", function(d){return d.key;})
    //add a useful class based on the data
    //d.key is the value used to create the nested array
    //i.e., the group value for all the bars in the <g>

    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.key); });
    //Set the style here and it will be inherited by the bars
    //in the group. If you set it on the individual rectangles, 
    //you will need to use d.group (the data property), 
    //not d.key (the property created by the nest method) 

bar.selectAll("rect").append("rect")
    .data(function(d) { return d.values; })
     //the nested sub-array for each group

  .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + main_x0(d.date) + ",0)"; 
     })
    .attr("x", function(d) { return main_x1(d.group); })
    //by using both a transform and an x-position, the two scales
    //are kept separate.  But make sure that you pass in the correct
    //data variable for each scale!  

    .attr("width", main_x1.rangeBand())
    //the width is calculated from the x1 scale, which positions
    //the individual bars within a cluster

    .attr("y", function(d) { return main_y(d.buildFixTime); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { 
             return main_height - main_y(d.buildFixTime); 
     });
    //note that these functions are based on a y-scale with an inverted range, 
    //one that goes from [main_height, 0], as I set up above
```

Again, if you want your bars grouped the other way around, you'll have to switch all your x0 scale functions to use `d.group`, and all your x1 scale functions to use `d.date`.

Comment: First, thank you - this was a great answer - very clear and easy to follow.  I am getting an error though implementing your code though.  This line: .attr("width", main_x1.rangeBand()) is giving me an "Invalid value for <rect> attribute width="Infinity"  Am I missing a step with the main_x1 object?

Comment: Sounds like the domain isn't being set, so you're getting a fixed interval divided by 0 groups = infinite width per group.  --And that's because of using the `d3.ascending` sort operator incorrectly.  Bug from your original code which I didn't catch.  The [ascending and descending functions](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-d3_ascending) don't sort the array directly, they are supposed to be passed in to the [`Array.sort` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). I'll correct the answer.

Comment: That did it - thank you so much for your help.  I'm going to look into the map function to understand what is going on with the domains.  Thanks again.

Comment: @AmeliaBR - How can we group data over multiple days in d3.js Let's say I have one month's data on each day basis. Key is date and value is Average google rank. I would like it to group by like this 1-3, 4-6, 7-9 which will represent average of rank over 3 days. Could you please guide?