# d3.js: ordinal scale and zoom/pan

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a basic D3 bar chart with ordinal x-scale and linear y-scale.

I've added zoom functionality and it works OK with the linear y-scale.

How can I get the x- scale to adjust accordingly with the zoom level?

Here's how it looks right now: http://jsfiddle.net/bM4HC/1/

The js below doesn't work with ordinal scales:

`d3.behavior.zoom()
    .x(x);`

Comment: [This example](http://bl.ocks.org/stepheneb/1182434) shows how to adjust x- and y-axes according to zoom.

Comment: The example references linear scales. I'm struggling with an ordinal one.

Comment: You can't link an ordinal scale to the zoom behaviour, because the zoom behaviour will try to change the domain of the scale using the `[min, max]` format for linear scales.  See [this related question about brushing functions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21492940/3128209) for a work-around, and let me know if there's anything else you can't figure out.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is the way to do it:

```
function zoom() {
  bars.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate[0]+",0)scale(" + d3.event.scale + ",1)");

  chart.select(".x.axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate[0]+","+(height)+")")
    .call(xAxis.scale(x.rangeRoundBands([0, width * d3.event.scale],.1 * d3.event.scale)));

  chart.select(".y.axis")
    .call(yAxis);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0917vvqt/

Just translate and scale the bars in X not x and y, also translate the xAxis with the d3.event.translate[0] (x axis).

**EDIT 1:**
Here is an updated example with *clip-path* :
http://jsfiddle.net/9rypxf10/

Comment: this is really helpful; thanks for sharing! how do you clip the data so the things outside the domain do not appear? i was using another d3 zoom example that used `clip-path`, but that doesn't seem to work when the svg elements are translated and scaled.

Comment: @dino You're welcome, using clip-path is the way to do it, here is an updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/9rypxf10/ .