# Zooming in D3 casts undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

I am trying to implementing zooming on my svg and am getting an undefined error when attempting to scroll with my mouse over the svg:

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Below I've pasted the code for how I added the zoom to my SVG. The "zoomHandler" function includes code, but I've tried emptying to test whether it was the content of it casting an undefined or not, and it makes no difference.

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .x(x)
    .scaleExtent([1, 10])
    .on("zoom", zoomHandler);

var svg = d3.select(".chart")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var svgbody = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "zoomClass")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
    .call(zoom);
```

***EDIT***

Added my js source:

```
var statusText = "Status";
var NODE_OPACITY = "0.7";
var circleSize = 10;
var squareSize = 19;

var margin = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 100 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], 1);

var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([height, 0], 1);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .tickValues([statusText])
    .orient("left");

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .x(x)
    .scaleExtent([1, 10])
    .on("zoom", zoomHandler);

var svg = d3.select(".chart")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var svgbody = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "zoomClass")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
    .call(zoom);

var rect = svgbody.append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .style("fill", "#fff");

var clip = svg.append("defs").append("svg:clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
    .append("svg:rect")
    .attr("id", "clip-rect")
    .attr("x", "0")
    .attr("y", "0")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
    x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.name; }));
    y.domain([statusText]);


    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);

    var circle = svgbody
        .selectAll("nodes.circle")
        .data(["F", "H"]);

    circle.exit()
        .style("opacity", 1)
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
        .style("opacity", 0)
        .remove();

    circle.enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("class", "circleNodes");

    circle
        .attr("cx", function(d){ return x(d);})
        .attr("cy", function(d){return y(statusText);} )
        .attr("r", circleSize)
        .style('opacity', NODE_OPACITY)
        .style('fill', "red");

    var square = svgbody
        .selectAll("nodes.rect")
        .data(["B", "L"]);

    square.exit()
        .style("opacity", 1)
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
        .style("opacity", 0)
        .remove();

    square.enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("class", "squareNodes");

    square
        .attr("x", function(d){ return x(d) - squareSize/2;;})
        .attr("y", function(d){return y(statusText) - squareSize/2;} )
        .attr("width", squareSize)
        .attr("height", squareSize)
        .attr("rx", "3")
        .attr("ry", "3" )
        .style('opacity', NODE_OPACITY)
        .style('fill', "green");

    /*var triangle = svg.selectAll("path")
        .data(["D", "P"]);

    triangle.exit()
        .style("opacity", 1)
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
        .style("opacity", 0)
        .remove();

    triangle.enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d) + "," + y(statusText) + ")"; })
        .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type("triangle-up"));

    var lineData = [ { "x": 1,   "y": 5},  { "x": 20,  "y": 20},
                  { "x": 40,  "y": 10}, { "x": 60,  "y": 40},
                  { "x": 80,  "y": 5},  { "x": 100, "y": 60}];

    var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
                         .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
                        .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
                         .interpolate("linear");

    var lineGraph = svg.append("path")
        .attr("d", lineFunction(lineData))
        .attr("stroke", "blue")
        .attr("stroke-width", 2)
        .attr("fill", "none");*/

});

function zoomHandler() {

    var translate = zoom.translate(),

    tx = Math.min(0, Math.max(width * (1 - scale), translate[0])),
    ty = Math.min(0, Math.max(height * (1 - scale), translate[1]));

    zoom.translate([tx, ty]);

    svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);

}

function type(d) {
  d.value = +d.value; // coerce to number
  return d;
}
```

Data:

```
name    value
A   1
B   1
C   1
D   1
E   1
F   1
G   1
H   1
I   1
J   1
K   1
L   1
M   1
N   1
O   1
P   1
Q   1
R   1
S   1
T   1
U   1
V   1
W   1
X   1
Y   1
Z   1
```

Comment: If you `console.log(zoomHandler)` right before `var zoom = d3.behavior...`, do you see a non-null value?

Comment: Hi, yeah it prints out my entire "zoomHandler" function, it isn't null.

Comment: @meetamit Do you have any suggestions to why I get this error when I attempt to execute my zoom?

Comment: Not without seeing the stack trace of the error (i.e. when you expand the error in the console). The line number associated with the error, is it referencing your code or d3.js?

Comment: Yes the error is in the d3.js file. Here's a screenshot of the error expanded: http://puu.sh/gmHtZ/76ddf2f2d2.png I use v3 of d3, if you need to know (which is the newest).

Comment: @meetamit I tried looking at line 1455 myself, but I do not understand what's happening at all :(

Comment: A fiddle or similar would help to figure out what's going on.  Short of that, can you post your entire source?

Comment: @Vanquiza Based on what I see around 1455, it seems like there might be something off with the scale `x`, perhaps it's that `x` is missing an `invert` method. Based on the previous question you posted here, `x` scale is ordinal. If so, then it makes sense, because ordinal scales don't have an `invert` method. In other words, using the `.x()` method of zoom is incompatible with ordinal scales. But do you even need to call `.x()`?

Comment: I added my js file content now. I am trying to create a fiddle to make it easier for you, but my data is in a tsv file. I am not sure on how to put this data into the fiddle and make it work correctly. I added the contents of my data file aswell.

Comment: @meetamit I am not sure whether I am supposed to call x or not. This is my first time attempting to implement zoom on D3, but what you have said makes sense. My question is however, how do I apply the zoom on my x-axis if I don't apply the scale? And why would I not need to apply the scale here?

Comment: @Vanquiza I think [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22070367/d3-js-ordinal-scale-and-zoom-pan) addresses what you need. See [the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0917vvqt/) of the answer. Looks like the solution involves adjusting the range of the ordinal scale, instead relying on the `d3.zoom.x()` method to do it.

Comment: Thank you, I'm looking into it already! I am having some problems with it but it solves the answer to this question though! So thanks alot!