# D3.js v5: How can I use filter() to get the data in the selected region of a brushable bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart, brush

I was trying to zoom the chart according to the data in the selected region using d3 brush. However, when I tried to use `dataselected` to receive the filtered data, it just returned an empty array after the selection had been done. I wonder if there is something wrong with my usage of filter() or anything else.

```js
brushed(selection){
  if (selection) {
    console.log(this.data); // Not empty
    let kw0 = this.xScale.invert(selection[0]);
    let kw1 = this.xScale.invert(selection[1]);
    this.xScale2 = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([kw0, kw1])
            .range([0, vis.width - vis.margin.right]);
    this.dataselected = this.data.filter(function(d){
            return (kw0 <= this.xScale(d)) && (this.xScale(d) <= kw1);
                });
    console.log(dataselected); // Empty array
  }
```

The selected bar chart:

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could log additional values like selection, this.xScale.invert(selection[0]) or this.xScale.invert(selection[1]).

Comment: Thanks I did that and those two values are the same. I had a check at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22873551/d3-js-brush-controls-getting-extent-width-coordinates just now. It seemed that I should use this.brush.extent() to get the coordinates but my vis.brush.extent()[0] was "undefined" in log. Was it because I used d3.brushX() to define this.brush? Why there wasn't an extent?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. No problem with the usage of filter. I used d.x0 and d.x1 instead of `this.xScale(d)` and it works.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).